# Validation Rule Issue - Why won't this work?

Tags: administration, validation, validation-rule

I've been trying to figure this out and cannot get it to work. I've tried the following combinations and nothing I do gets it to trigger.

We have a lookup field that looks up to the Sales Order object, and relates it back to a specific quote. The purpose of the validation rule is that if the fields denoted below are blank, a Sales Order CANNOT be populated/related.

```
 IF(ISCHANGED(PBSI__Sales_Order__c), 

 AND( 
 ISBLANK(Panels__c), 
 ISBLANK(Contract_System_Size_Watts__c), 
 ISBLANK(Usage_Offset__c) 
 ), 

 false)
```

Number 2 attempt:

```
 IF(!ISBLANK(PBSI__Sales_Order__c), 

 AND( 
 ISBLANK(Panels__c), 
 ISBLANK(Contract_System_Size_Watts__c), 
 ISBLANK(Usage_Offset__c) 
 ), 

 false)
```

Number 3 attempt:

```
 AND( 
 !ISBLANK(PBSI__Sales_Order__c),
 ISBLANK(Panels__c), 
 ISBLANK(Contract_System_Size_Watts__c), 
 ISBLANK(Usage_Offset__c) 
 )
```

Attempt 4:

```
AND( 
ISCHANGED(PBSI__Sales_Order__c),
ISBLANK(Panels__c), 
ISBLANK(Contract_System_Size_Watts__c), 
ISBLANK(Usage_Offset__c) 
)
```

I'm certain it's logical in nature. I'm not sure I'm looking at validation rules properly in my head. If someone could show how it is supposed to look to work, and then break it down explaining why it works, I would appreciate it.

Thanks!

Comment: Is changed doesn't fire on new records. That might help w some of the scenarios. Also, the ANDs mean that all of the fields have to be blank to be true.  One way to test these is to create new checkbox formula fields on the object so you can see how it evaluates.  Will look at this in detail when I get a chance if nobody else gets you the answer by then.

Comment: Attempt 3 looks legit for me. Do you want this to trigger only when all 3 fields are blank and PBSI__Sales_Order__c is populated?

Comment: Did you try swapping `ISNULL` in for `ISBLANK`?

Comment: @Oleksiy It's to prevent PBSI__Sales_Order__c from being populated if the other fields haven't had information entered into them yet.

Comment: @gorav This particular one _should_ only need to trigger during updates. New records of this object shouldn't need to have this fire for it. I'll try your checkbox method as I continue to play with this. At the moment I haven't gotten it working yet.

Comment: @AdrianLarson I tried swapping the ISBLANKS for ISNULL using code simiilar to my examples 2 and 3 and still couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try that:

```
 AND( 
 NOT(ISBLANK(PBSI__Sales_Order__c)),
 OR(
 ISBLANK(Panels__c), 
 ISBLANK(Contract_System_Size_Watts__c), 
 ISBLANK(Usage_Offset__c))
 )
```

Comment: This worked! Thanks! I'm comparing it to my own code and am trying to break down the logic for how it works, so I can better understand what I am doing next time.

Answer (score 0):

Set validation rule condition as only

```
AND( ISBLANK(Panels__c), ISBLANK(Contract_System_Size_Watts__c), ISBLANK(Usage_Offset__c) )
```